# Create and android Alarm and get Notification

Tags: java, android

I can set dates, times, and type whatever ask I won't successfully and reminders. I do not have receive any error, but I don't have receive any notification, when the task is set. These are my code snippet below:

this is my set alarm class:

> private void setAlarm( String text, String date, String time){
> AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
>
> ```
> //create an intent to show notification
> ```
>
> Intent intent = new Intent(CreateTask.this, TaskNotificationAlarm.class);
> intent.putExtra("event", text);
> intent.putExtra("time", date);
> intent.putExtra("date", time);
>
> PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
> String dateandtime = date + " " +  timeTonotify;
> DateFormat formatter =  new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy hh:mm");
> try {
> Date date1 = formatter.parse(dateandtime);
> alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date1.getTime(), pendingIntent);
> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> catch (ParseException e) {
> e.printStackTrace();
> }
>
> Intent intentBack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TaskActivity.class);
> intentBack.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
> startActivity(intentBack);
> }

```
this is my notification class:
```

> public class TaskNotificationAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
> @Override
> public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
> Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
> String text =  bundle.getString("event");
> String description =  bundle.getString("event description");
> String date = bundle.getString("date") + "" + bundle.getString("time");
>
> Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlertDetails.class);
> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
> intent1.putExtra("message", text);
>
> PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
> NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
> NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notify_001");
>
> RemoteViews contentView =  new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_notification);
> PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
> contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.flashButton, pendingSwitchIntent);
> contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.message, text);
> contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.date, date);
> builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_calendar);
> builder.setAutoCancel(true);
> builder.setOngoing(true);
> builder.setAutoCancel(true);
> builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
> builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
> builder.build().flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH;
> builder.setContent(contentView);
> builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
>
> if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
> String channelId =  "channel_id";
> NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
> channel.enableVibration(true);
> notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
> builder.setChannelId(channelId);
> }
> Notification notification = builder.build();
> notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
> }
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fellow coder.

I think the issue is that the notification channel is not able to identify the builder.

I would suggest you to create notification channel first then create the builder,declare channel's variable globally in the file.

Also you should separate your notification channel creation code and notification builder code into two separate methods and call it at ones in your `onReceive()`(TaskNotificationAlarm) in broadcast receiver such as

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
  // Write your channel creation code here
  Log.d("TAG","Notification Channel Running")
}
private void createNotification() {
// Write your notification builder code here
Log.d("TAG","Notification Builder Running")
}
```

Don't Forget to mention your broadcast receiver class in your manifest file like this :

```
<receiver
        android:name=".TaskNotificationAlarm"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Make sure you mention this receiver inside `<application></application>` tag.

- Try to fire logs as shown in the code section to verify that the the method is getting called or not.
- Start a debugging point at the position where the BroadcastReceiver's code is fired.

Try using `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` method of Alarm Manager to trigger alarm, this method will allow the OS to trigger alarm even if the device is on battery saver or low power mode.

```
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle (int type, 
            long triggerAtMillis, 
            PendingIntent operation)
```

And to cancel the alarm you just have to use the predefined `alarmManager.cancel()` method

For more detailed understanding in Alarm Manager [Click Me](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: Hi there, thanks it works now. The only challenge now is when I set another alarm, it is the notification of the first alarm I get. For example, lets say I set the first alarm to "11:08am", if I add another alarm for maybe "11:15am". I get notification of "11:08am".

Comment: Hello, great to hear that it worked, I'm guessing that the reason behind getting the same notification time is that either it is overwriting the old notification over the newer one or cannot identify the current notification id. The probable solution can be done by using a common service class for firing alarm, where you can manage both the notification and alarm firing. Can you share your files for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

The `alarmManager.set` will fire the alarm at an approximate time and not at the exact time. In order to show the exact alarm you need to use

`alarmManager.setAlarmClock()`

For more details check this out [Schedule alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)